# C++ getters and setters not passing variables

Tags: c++, class, object, getter, setter

In the following two lines of code, it should get the name of the player and then set that name to the owner of the property. When i run it, it simply just outputs "Owner: "

*player.cpp*

```
gb.getProperty(position).setOwner(name);
cout << "Owner: " << gb.getProperty(position).getOwner() << endl;
```

it should print the name of the player whos turn it is, i have already checked that the name is correct so im led to believe it is the getters and setters for the owner:
Here are my getters and setters for the owner, have i done anything wrong here?

*board.h*

```
class properties {

public:

    string getOwner() { return owner; }
    void setOwner(string o) { owner = o; }

private:

    string owner;
};
```

all my files are connected appropriately, any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is `name ` properly initialized?

Comment: How is `getProperty` implemented? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: My guess is that `getProperty` returns a copy instead of a reference

Comment: initialised in the public section of class properties by 'string getProperty() {return name;}' and 'string name' in the private section

Answer (score 1):

Although your code is not reproducible, I can guess that your `getProperty` return a value rather than a reference. Change it to a reference may solve your problem.